# Can't swap lines in an array[2][2]. It seems that it does something out of array

Tags: c, arrays

Can't swap lines in an array[2][2]. It seems that it does something out of array. *(I suspect that this code has gone crazy (mad)*

**1)** I print it. **2)** *Trying to swap* (thinking that the problem is nearly there). **3)** I print it again. (but now the values of elements are not as they were before)

```
#include <stdio.h>#
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define RANGE 99

int main()
{
    int l1,l2;
    int i,j;
    int arr[2][2];       // There should be arr[3][3]. FOR MORE 
    int temp_line[2];    // DETAILS SEE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER.

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    /* Filling in */
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 1 + rand()%RANGE;
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Displaying */
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            printf("%2.d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    printf("\nEnter the No. of lines to swap them.\n"); // Remember about the 0th element.
    scanf("%d%d", &l1, &l2);   // The 1-st and the 2-nd lines.


    /** Swapping lines. PROBLEM!  */
    for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            temp_line[j] = arr[l1][j];  // Remember the 1-st required line.

    for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        arr[l1][j] = arr[l2][j];    // Copying each element of the 2-nd required line 1-st one.

    for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        arr[l2][j] = temp_line[j];  //  Copying "Remembered" 1-st required line.


    /* Displaying */
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            printf("%2.d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh... `arr[2]` has length *2*, not *3*. Therein lies at least parts of your problem (and the point at which I stopped reading). As soon as you access element 2, i.e. the third element, you're out of bounds.

Comment: I think that array[2][2] includes array[0][0]...
So I don't understand what did you want to tell me.

Comment: You enumerate the elements counting from zero. So `foo[0]` is the first element of `foo`, `foo[1]` is the second, etc. However, when declaring the array, you specify the *number of elements*. So `int foo[1]` declares an array of *one* `int`, while `int foo[2]` declares one of *two* `int`s. This has nothing to do with the fact that the first element is referred to as "element number zero".

Comment: In other words: Even if you label houses on a street from `0` to `n-1`, you still say that the street has `n` houses on it. The street having `n` houses on it does not in any way preclude house number 0 from being on the street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 3x3 array should be declared as:

```
int arr[3][3];  // Array 3x3
```

When declaring an array the numbers indicate how many "slots" to allocate. Since you want a 3x3 array, you need to specify a `3`.

When accessing an array you specify the index. Indices start with 0, so if you want to access the first element you use a `0`.

The Count and the Index are two distinct things.

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot: The columns have length *11* and the rows length *6* in that diagram. Count them. `balances[3][4]` refers to the fifth entry on the fourth row. (Edit: "that diagram" here refers to a diagram OP linked to and then deleted suddenly).

Comment: If it helps, think of an ordinary (i.e. "1d") array of `int`s instead. Your confusion is just as relevant there.

Comment: Understood! For about several years I thought so, but now I see that I was wrong..

Answer (score 1):

The array has 2 elements but with `for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)` you iterate one past the end.

It must be 
`for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)`.